# Sencha Touch 2 Tab Panels with many tabs

Tags: sencha-touch-2, uitabbar

In Sencha Touch 2, the TabPanel is really great when you've got 5 or less tabs. Any more than that, and it doesn't fit on a phone in portrait mode (see [this fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#8SNhb)).

What are my options? Is there any way to make the last button pop up a sub-TabBar? or can I put an arrow on the right end of the TabBar that makes the bar slide over for a new one? or can I make the TabBar scrollable?

Comment: If you come across an answer, please post it here as well, thanks!

Comment: @Simon See [Naresh Tank's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536495/1431146)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the tab bar scrollable using the following config:

```
    tabBar: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'horizontal'
        }
    },
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#8SNhb#bAUl3).

Comment: Awesome! I'd still like some opinions on this solution from a usability perspective, but it definitely solves my problem!

Comment: Yeah, it solves the problem, but I don't think this is what users will be expecting - I certainly wouldn't think to scroll on the main menu like that.